# install4j: how can i reuse the java code from the action script field in different Installer projects?

Tags: install4j

we build installer for several projects with similar tasks like configure and check DB Connections for different DB types. How can i reuse the java-code snippets inside the scriptfields to avoid code dups ?

Answer (score 2):

Within a single project, common scripts can be defined on the "Installer->Custom code & resources" step by clicking on the "Edit code" button.

To reuse code across projects, you would have to write it in your JRE, create a JAR file  from the compiled classes and add it on the "Installer->Custom code & resources" step.

See the [API overview page](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/) on how to set up the API runtime in your IDE.